# Как будет корректно: "по своей природе" или "в своей природе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Одинаковы по своей природе" или "одинаковы в своей природе"?

Comment: Возможны оба варианта. Приведите контекст, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

"Коррэктно" (излюбленное словцо Грамоты.ру) - по своей природе.

Учебник(и):

> Приведите примеры, показывающие, что силы, возникающие в результате
>   взаимодействия двух тел, ***одинаковы по своей природе***.
>
> Как отличается ***по своей природе*** электропроводность металлов и
>   электролитов?
>
> Искусство ***по своей природе***: а) рационально; б) эмоционально; в)
>   сочетает в себе и рациональное, и эмоциональное начала.

Другой как бы учебник (["Человек ***по своей природе*** добр"](http://knigi.link/etika/chelovek-svoey-prirode-7787.html)):

> Существуют разные мнения относительно того, добр или зол человек ***по
>   своей природе***. Одни считают, что человек ***по природе*** добр,
>   другие, что он зол, третьи — что он не добр и не зол.

Если убрать одинаковость, то и природа приобретёт другое значение (стало быть, возможен другой предлог):

> «Наука открыла нам, что человек, происходя от животного, имеет ***в своей
>   природе*** как хорошие, так и дурные свойства и что именно последние
>   делают существование наше столь несчастным».
>
> ---
>
> «Если Бог не материален, то откуда материя? Каким образом
>   количественное от неколичественного, видимое от невидимого, непременно
>   определяемое объемом и величиною от не имеющего величины и
>   определенного очертания, и все прочее, усматриваемое в материи, — как
>   и откуда произвел Тот, Кто не имеет ничего подобного ***в Своей
>   природе***?»

Answer (score 0):

1) **При сравнении** чаще используется вариант "**одинаковы по своей природе**" (эти силы одинаковы **по своей природе**), выражение "одинаковы в своей природе" кажется устаревшим.

Также сочетание  "по своей природе" используется в значении "с точки зрения природы", например: Митрофан не злой **по своей природе**.

2) В то же время падежная форма "в своей природе" используется в других ситуациях, когда говорится о природных (естественных) качествах чего-либо или кого-либо, например: Но **в своей природе** она одна и та же. Добро и зло не переменились ли **в своей природе**? Митрофан,  ничего не заключая злобного **в своей природе**, становится  тираном всех.